# transition between activities - "back button" animation

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, transition

I want that when a certain `view` in my app is clicked, it will switch to another `activity` but with a different transition - instead of the regular slide to right transition, I want it to be the exact opposite.

Now, I have managed to do this with the following code:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            v.vibrate(50);
            Intent back = new Intent(Course.this, Classes.class);
            back.putExtra("lvl", lvl);
            startActivity(back);
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
            finish();
        }
```

Problem is, when I click this `view` the transition happens as planned but the first `view` goes completely black. So, the animation is working but im not seeing an animation that i want - that the screen is sliding left, because the first `activity` disappears before the transition is done. This happens also when i remove the `finish();` command.

How could this be done? Thanks!

Comment: post the XML you are using for the animation.

Comment: I don't know the XML, as you can see it is a built in android animation in `android.R...`